# Which plane am I flying on?

Tags: air-travel, jfk, dub

Flying on DL45 from Dublin to JFK soon. On Delta airlines website it says I'm on A330-300 but it used to say 767-400. Using this site (https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/dl45) shows all previous flights were on a 767-400.

I paid for an upgraded seat and I'm concerned if the seat plan is different between the 767-400 and A330-300, so I'm unsure if my upgrade will carry over. Any suggestions?

Also, when searching "DL45 which plane" it states: 'DL45 is a Delta Air Lines flight from Dublin to New York . The flight has a distance of 5108 km (3155 mi.) with an average flight time of 7h 54m. It is operated on a daily basis using Boeing B767-400 Planes.'.

How does it work with the seat plan, giving that each plane houses a different number of passengers? And what do I go off of? The airline website or other sites I am seeing?

Comment: from my work experience (See below), looking at that flightradar, I'd trust that. It's more likely a 767.  Possibly Delta's website is out of date.

Comment: Delta's site used to say a 767 then recently changed to A330. I also just checked SeatGuru which, when inputting my flight number and dates, it gives an A330 300. Interesting. I suppose I'll just have to turn up and see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did a contract at a major Australian airline, where I was required to fly on specific planes on specific days.

Even up to 30 min before, our own internal systems might show one plane, and then engineering or Ops would switch them.

So the first point, is especially on busy routes, you can't always guarantee which plane you'll be on.

As for the seat plan - correct, you can't fit x passengers on a plane with less than x seats.  Those passengers might be bumped to a later flight. That's assuming it was a full plane though - might just be fewer empty seats.

We used to use flightradar24 and flightaware if we didn't have access to our own internal applications.

But even when I had those, and knew which plane I wanted, there wasn't a guarantee. Even had a 737 switched out for a 330. Happens :/

Comment: That's certainly interesting. I've only had this happen once when I was due to fly on a A330 and it changed a day before the travel to a 777 (again with Delta). I will just keep an eye on it and see what happens. This pretty much answers my question, so thanks.

Comment: It can even happen **after** scheduled departure time. Had an EasyJet flight once where there was a technical issue with the aircraft, and after trying to fix it for a little while (which delayed departure), they finally switched aircraft, and ended up with a 320 instead of a 321. Of course, they started asking for volunteers to be rebooked on a later flight...

Answer (score 2):

Delta's Dublin to JFK flight changes from a 767 to an A330 starting next Friday, the 31st of January.  This change was [announced](https://simpleflying.com/delta-767-to-a330-replacement/) back in May of 2019.

Whilst looking at the flight history is often a good indication of the type of plane that will fly future flights, they do change over time, however in general these changes will be reflected on the carriers website well in advance (generally months ahead of time) to avoid any issues like those you've stated around different numbers of seats being available/different seat numbering/etc.

It is always possible that the aircraft type will change very close to the flight, especially when there is bad weather as the airline shuffles flights to use which aircraft are available, but this is rare.